# Upload files via jquery $.post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, upload

For send ajax form i use this code :

```
<input type="file" class="file_1" id="file" />
```

- note : not use "FORM" tag

My jQuery code :

```
var file = $('#file').val();
$.post('form.php', {file:file}, function(data){});
```

And my PHP code :

```
if($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] != '') {
            $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
            $fileType = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
            $fileSize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
        }
echo $fileName;
```

But this code not work

Comment: jQuery can't do file uploads by itself. See the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload file asnychronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581126/how-to-upload-file-asynchronously-using-jquery)

Comment: How use ajax for this ?!

Comment: jQuery CAN do files uploads by itself.  So many people don't understand how this works, it seems.  Google is your friend, really.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can´t.
Nevertheless, there are some tools that "emulate" it.
Check up this tutorial:
http://hayageek.com/ajax-file-upload-jquery/

Or this question:
[Is it possible to use Ajax to do file upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543926/is-it-possible-to-use-ajax-to-do-file-upload)

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to post a adress name (on the other words you post a string) but file upload needs to be a file. 
then you can find the answer from the this link:

[Uploading both data and files in one form using Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax)